# Android 5.0 Lollipop notification full sound doesn't play

Tags: android, audio, notifications, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an alarm app that plays a sound (alarm-like continuous audio) when the alarm goes off. Unfortunately, in Lollipop the sound doesn't play in full, instead it gets stopped after a couple of seconds. But if the phone is connected to power, this doesn't happen and the sound actually is played fully. The code works fine on previous versions of Android. Can anyone please help? Here's my code for the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .setContentTitle(someTitle)
                .setWhen(now)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.some_icon);

Notification notif = mBuilder.build();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    notif.sound = audioFileUri;
    notif.category = Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM;

    AudioAttributes.Builder attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
    attrs.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION);
    attrs.setUsage(useAlarm ? AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM : AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_EVENT);
    notif.audioAttributes = attrs.build();
} else  {
    mBuilder.setSound(audioFileUri, useAlarm ? AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM : AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
    notif = mBuilder.build();
}

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and most likely this is due to the new power saving settings in Lollipop, so the device goes to sleep while the sound is playing.

My solution to this issue is to use the MediaPlayer class to play the sound as it allows setting the wakemode. For this to work you need also to to add wake_lock to your permission in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Here is how to use MediaPlayer:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .setContentTitle(someTitle)
            .setWhen(now)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.some_icon);

Notification notif = mBuilder.build();

MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, audioFileUri);
player.setAudioStreamType(am.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setWakeMode(context, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK); //<< the important part
player.start();

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
```